# How can I get display block to work on mobile devices and older versions of firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a HTML menu that I have that looks fine on chrome, the latest firefox, and IE, however it looks like garbage on my ipad and old version of firefox.  Is there any way to make this work everywhere?

HTML:

```
    <div id="navbar">

            <ul>
                <a href=/interpreters.php><li> Interpreters</li></a>
                <li>Onsite
                    <ul>
                        <a href=/displayappointments.php?lookup=todayScheduled><li>Appointment Manager</li></a>
                        <a href =/newapp.php><li>New Appointment</li></a>
                    </ul></li>
                <li>Telephonic
                    <ul>
                        <a href =/otp.php><li>New Call</li></a>
                        <a href =/otplog.php><li>OTP Log</li></a>
                        <a href =/otpraw.php><li>OTP Raw</li></a>
                    </ul></li>    
                <a href=/translation.php><li>Translation</li></a>
                <li>Tools
                    <ul>
                        <a href=/teammessage.php><li>Team Message</li></a>
                        <a href=massemail.php><li>Mass Email</li></a>
                        <a href=uofuparser.php><li>U of U</li></a>
                        <a href=/incidenttracker/submitincident.php><li>Issue Tracker <? echo $count; ?></li></a>
                        <a href=medicaid.php><li>Medicaid<? echo $medcount; ?></li></a>
                     </ul></li>       
                <a href=sms.php><li>TXT<? echo $smscount; ?></li></a>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #navbar {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: center; 
    }

    #navbar ul {      
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center; 
    }

    #navbar ul li {
    float:left;
    color:#333366;
    padding:0 8px 0 8px;
    border-right:1px solid #0099FF;
    border-left:1px solid #0099FF;
    height:3SS0px;
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius: 9px;
    border-top-right-radius: 9px;
    }

    #navbar ul li:hover {
    background-color:#e8edff;
    }

    #navbar ul li ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:transparent;
    padding:10px;
    opacity:0.95;
    }

    #navbar ul li ul li{
    float:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:150px;
    color:#333366;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    z-index:100;
    }

    #navbar ul li ul li a{
    color:#333366;
    text-decoration:none;
    }

    #navbar ul li ul li a:hover{
    color:#333366;
    }   

    #navbar ul li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
    }
```

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/n9TGH/

When displayed correctly it looks like this: [image: Correct]
On my iPad and older versions of firefox it looks like this: [image: Wrong]

Comment: What about it on mobile and iPad is bothering you? How are they supposed to look?

Comment: @Seth I just added two images, one showing correctly and the other from my iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through your HTML code I noticed that it isn't well formatted. When you use `<li>` they should be on the outside of your `HREF` tags. Also you didnt specify an ending `</ul>` tag. Modern browsers are way more forgiving then their older versions. Try this code and see if it helps.

```
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=/interpreters.php>Interpreters</a></li>
        <li>Onsite
            <ul>
                <li><a href=/displayappointments.php?lookup=todayScheduled>Appointment Manager</a></li>
                <li><a href=/newapp.php>New Appointment</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Telephonic
            <ul>
                <li><a href =/otp.php>New Call</a></li>
                <li><a href =/otplog.php>OTP Log</a></li>
                <li><a href =/otpraw.php>OTP Raw</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href=/translation.php>Translation</a></li>
        <li>Tools
            <ul>
                <li><a href=/teammessage.php>Team Message</a></li>
                <li><a href=massemail.php>Mass Email</a></li>
                <li><a href=uofuparser.php>U of U</a></li>
                <li><a href=/incidenttracker/submitincident.php>Issue Tracker <? echo $count; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href=medicaid.php>Medicaid<? echo $medcount; ?></a></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href=sms.php><li>TXT<? echo $smscount; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I need to pay a bit more attention there.

Comment: Glad that helped. I just noticed that I forgot to remove one extra <li> tag in the last list item.